# How could i have a platform not be affected by other rigidbodies without turning it to kinematic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d platformer and there's a part where there are platforms, and I need the player to step on them but it moves the platform down when that happens and I can't set it to kinematic because that would make forces not able to be applied to it. So how could I make the player not able to move it without setting it to kinematic?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ButterPlatCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject plat;
    public Vector2 pos;
    private bool instantiated = false;
    public float platspeed;

    void Start()
    {
        platspeed = 5;
        InvokeRepeating("Duplicate", 1.5f, 1.5f);
        InvokeRepeating("Speed", 1.5f, 1.5f);
    }

    void Speed()
    {
        platspeed = platspeed + 0.5f;
    }

    void Duplicate()
    {
        if (!instantiated)
        {
            Debug.Log("Duplicated");
            GameObject newPlat = Instantiate(plat, new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y), Quaternion.identity);
            Rigidbody2D platbody = newPlat.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            platbody.AddForce(-transform.right * 5, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            instantiated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Kinematic does not mean you can not move it, it means you have to move it yourself. In general using a Force which is part of the physics system is bad if you want to move something artificially. What you most likely should do is adjust the platforms position instead of applying a force. 
The only reason, which i don't see here, would be if you want to have it slow down with friction or something on a specific axis which would be possible by locking the axis which you don't want to move in the rigidbody.